# Mediafiles compression program

Tags: video, compression, media, image

Can anybody recommend a good compression programm wich i can use to compress pictures/videos? i cant really reduce their size during transport.

thank you.

Comment: The common media file formats are already compressed: PNG, JPEG, MP4, WEBM.  Compare the size of an uncompressed BMP for example.

Comment: What platform? What environment? lossless or lossy? Does it have to run in certain constraints on client systems or does it run on servers with all kinds of cool tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.stuffit.com/ - jpeg,tiff,mp3,pdf  
http://soundslimmer.com/ - mp3
http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm - jpeg,wav

http://schnaader.info/precomp.php - deflate-based formats, jpeg
http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/ - jpeg
http://paq8.hys.cz/ - jpeg,bmp,wav

Answer (score 0):

http://www.klaimsoft.com/winuha/ comes to mind.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Did you click the link? What exactly is there "essential" on WinUHA's site?

Answer (score 0):

Pictures and videos are two wholly different things. Unless you want lossless compression but it is hard to compress video/audio files more than +-10% as the algorithms behind the file formats are already pretty effective.

For transcoding (putting into a different format) video files [Mediacoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) is free and versatile, but hard to grasp for beginners. There are 3 main things that determine file size and quality: Coded, resolution and bitrate. For codec you should choose a modern one like WebM or H.264, or at least Xvid or another MPEG4 codec. Resolution determines the number of pixels and is pretty straightforward. Bitrate mean number of bits per frame and depends on the resolution and codec used.

For pictures generally only resolution is the problem: cameras make pictures in resolutions far larger than a computer screen can show. For just general showing (not printing) 1024x786 or around is usually enough. You can resize pictures through special batch resizers, [a free one from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) is avaialable for Windows XP.